# change style through checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

I'm working ona fullcalendar project.

I have these 2 [checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUYMn.png) (Ore Personali e Assenze), when they are checked they should hide the events but at the moment they are not doing it.

This is my **input checkbox**:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="OP" name="calendario" value="OP">
```

And this is the **function** i've build so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
                var checkBox = document.getElementById("OP");
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("fc-event-container");
                if (checkBox.checked === true){
                    x.style.visibility = "visible !important";
                }else{
                    x.style.visibility = "hidden !important";
                }
            })
        })
```

I build it by looking on the internet cause i'm new to JS and dont know much, just basic stuff.
And it's giving error in the *x.style* part (telling me is undefined).
Can someone explain to me how i should do it, cause on internet i only found this way and some other who's just giving me errors anyway.

thanks in advances whos gonna help me (or at least try)

---

i did as @Cypherjac suggest and it worked.

But now it just hide the events on the current month, when i change months i have to checked and unchecked to hide. Even if i go back to the month i hid the events they are visible
Is there a way to let them stay hide even if i change month?

---

Before i update the code i will specify that this is not my code, my fullcalendar is from a template i found on internet, i add the function i needed but most of th stuff was already there:

**calendar.js code:**

```
key: 'handleFullcalendar',
    value: function handleFullcalendar() {
    
        var myOptions = {
            header: {
                left: 'today',
                center: 'prev,title,next',
                right: 'none',


            },
            
            buttonText:{
                today: 'Oggi',
                month: 'Mese',
                week: 'Settimana',
                day: 'Giorno'
            },
            
            locale:'it',        
            allDaySlot: false,  
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,               
            timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',             
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Calendari',
            
            resources: [
                {
                    id: 'a',
                    title: 'Ore Personali'
                },
                {
                    id: 'b',
                    title: 'Assenze'
                }
            ],
            
            windowResize: function windowResize(view) {
                var width = $(window).outerWidth();
                var options = Object.assign({}, myOptions);

                options.events = view.calendar.clientEvents();
                options.aspectRatio = width < 667 ? 0.5 : 1.35;

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar(options);
            },
            
    //_______apre modal per aggiungere nuovo evento
        select: function select(event) {                
            $('#addNewEvent').modal('show');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents',event._id)
        },
            
    //_______________ELIMINARE EVENTO TRAMITE X
    
         eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
            if (view.name == 'listDay') {
                element.find(".fc-list-item-time").append("<span class='closeon'>X</span>");
            } else {
                element.find(".fc-content").prepend("<span class='closeon'>X</span>");
            }
            element.find(".closeon").on('click', function() {
                var deleteMsg = confirm("Vuoi davvero eliminare " + event.title + "?");
                if (deleteMsg == true) {                        
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'eventi/deleteEvent.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data:  {_id: event.idAssenza, nomeUtente: event.nomeUtente},
                        success: function(html){
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    })
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
                }else{
                    location.reload();
                }
            })
        }, 
                        
        //triggherà apertura modal di #editEvent
        eventClick: function eventClick(event) {
            var color = event.backgroundColor ? event.backgroundColor : (0, _Config.colors)('blue', 600);
            $('#editEname').val(event.title);
            $('event.id').val(event.idAssenza);
            $('nomeUtente').val(event.nomeUtente);
            $('#editStarts').val(event.start.toISOString());
            $('#editEnds').val(event.end.toISOString());
            $('#editNewEvent').modal('show').one('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                event.title = $('#editEname').val();
                event.start = $('#editStarts').val();
                event.end = $('#editEnds').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'eventi/updateEvent.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:  {start: event.start, _id: event.idAssenza, end: event.end, title: event.title, },
                    success: function(html){
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event._id);
            });
        }, 

            

            events: {                   
                url: 'eventi/load.php', 
                method:'POST'
                //color: <- fare in modo che prenda i colori scelti nel modal
                
            },
            droppable: false
        };
        
{       
    $(function() {
        $('#OP').change(function() {
            var x = $('.fc-event-container');
            // Access the element using jQuery
            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                x.css({
                    'visibility': 'visible'
                })
            }
            else {
                x.css({
                    'visibility': 'hidden'
                })
            }
        })
    });
},

        var _options = void 0;
        var myOptionsMobile = Object.assign({}, myOptions);

        myOptionsMobile.aspectRatio = 0.5;
        _options = $(window).outerWidth() < 667 ? myOptionsMobile : myOptions;

        $('#editNewEvent').modal();
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(_options);
    }
```

**Calendar.php:**

```
    <?php 
  require_once "config.php";
  session_start(); 
   if(!ISSET($_SESSION['nomeUtente'])){
    header('location:login/login.php');
   }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js css-menubar" locale="it">
  <head>

    <!-- Meta Tag -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="description" content="bootstrap material admin template">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    
    <title> Calendario | E.D. Elettronica Dedicata </title>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="page">
      <div class="page-aside">
        <div class="page-aside-switch">
          <i class="icon md-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="icon md-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="page-aside-inner page-aside-scroll">
          <div data-role="container">
            <div data-role="content">
<!--LISTA CALENDARI-->
              <section class="page-aside-section">
                <h5 class="page-aside-title">Lista calendari di <?php echo $_SESSION["nomeUtente"]; ?></h5>
                <div class="list-group has-actions">                  
                  <div class="list-group-item" data-plugin="editlist">
                    <div class="list-content">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="OP" name="calendario" value="OP" checked>
                      <span class="list-text"><a href="calendarOP.php">Ore Personali</a></span>
                    </div>                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="list-group-item" data-plugin="editlist">
                    <div class="list-content">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="assenze" name="calendario" value="assenze">
                      <span class="list-text"><a href="calendar.php">Assenze</a></span>                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-editable">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </section>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="page-main">
        <div class="calendar-container">
          <div id="calendar"></div>

<!--addEvent Dialog -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="addNewEvent" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="addNewEvent"
            role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-simple">
              <form class="modal-content form-horizontal" action="eventi/addEvent.php" method="post" role="form">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Aggiungi Assenza (<?php echo $_SESSION["nomeUtente"]; ?>)</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group row" id=editColor>
                    <label class="form-control-label col-md-2">Tipo:</label>
                    <input list="assenza" name="ename" id="ename" style="margin-left: 15px;" />
                    <datalist id="assenza">
                      <option value="Normali">
                        <option value="Straordinarie">
                      <option value="Ferie">
                      <option value="Malattia">
                      <option value="Permesso">
                        <option value="Smart Working">
                      <option value="Altro">
                    </datalist>
                    <input type="hidden" name="nomeUtente" id="nomeUtente" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["nomeUtente"]; ?>">                     
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-2 form-control-label" for="starts">Inizio:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="starts" name="starts" data-container="#addNewEvent">                 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-2 form-control-label" for="ends">Fine:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="ends" name="ends" data-container="#addNewEvent">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>                  
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <div class="form-actions">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Aggiungi Assenza">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-pure" data-dismiss="modal" href="javascript:void(0)">Annulla</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End AddEvent Dialog -->

<!-- editEvent Dialog -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="editNewEvent" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="editNewEvent"
            role="dialog" tabindex="-1" data-show="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-simple">
              <form class="modal-content form-horizontal" action="eventi/deleteEvent.php" method="POST" role="form">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modifica Assenza (<?php echo $_SESSION["nomeUtente"]; ?>)</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="form-control-label col-md-2" for="editEname">Tipo:</label>
                    <input list="assenza" name="editEname" id="editEname" style="margin-left: 15px;" />
                    <datalist id="assenza">
                      <option value="Normali">
                        <option value="Straordinarie">
                      <option value="Ferie">
                      <option value="Malattia">
                      <option value="Permesso">
                        <option value="Smart Working">
                      <option value="Altro">
                    </datalist> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="nomeUtente" id="nomeUtente" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["nomeUtente"]; ?>">  
                  </div>                  
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-2 form-control-label" for="editStarts">Inizio:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="editStarts" name="editStarts" data-container="#editNewEvent">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-2 form-control-label" for="editEnds">Fine:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="editEnds" name="editEnds"data-container="#editNewEvent">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <div class="form-actions">

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Salva modifiche</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-pure" data-dismiss="modal" href="javascript:void(0)">Annulla</a>
                  </div>                  
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End EditEvent Dialog -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

This is the [template](https://github.com/rohitgehe05/remark-admin-template/tree/master/material/center) i'm using it, most of the code it's there, i just update the part i'm using and modifing

Comment: HI, instead of click event please try on change event and then check if check box is checked then impose your style accordingly

Comment: For that extra functionality you will need to provide some more code including the one for the fullcalendar

Comment: Okay, like the one from JS file right?

Comment: Yes, not necessarily everything but enough to be able to reproduce it

Comment: i updated it, if u need something else, pls tell me thanks

Comment: oh to reproduce it maybe you also need my calendar page, right?

Comment: Yes, it has to be minimally reproducible

Comment: okay, i'm gonna try

Comment: done, but i repeat it, if you need something else, pls tell me

Comment: Here's what I can tell you about this, I have recreated the same scenario with my own code so you can test out what you're talking about.. Your example is not accurate since as you've said you got it from somewhere.. For example the first line of the calendar.js is an incomplete object

Comment: So check this https://codepen.io/cypherjac/pen/VwyKQYZ?editors=1010 for an example that is minimal without a lot of stuff and is a good playground to test out what you are talking about .. I didn't fully understand your final request about the events but this is a good playground for that.. Kindly update me with what you want exactly based on this codepen

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help and time

Comment: based on this codepen, as u can see, if you hide an event on march and then go to april, the events in april are visible, when for me it's would be nice to have the events hide even if i change month

Comment: Just seen this, check my edited answer for an explanation then check the codepen for the demo.. That all I can help you upto my might, so you can read further, but the concept you need is explained in my answer

Comment: Okay, thanks you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using **jQuery**, you can use it to access the elements instead of native js

Here `$(this).prop('checked')` is being used to check the **checked** property of the checkbox

Then when it changes, change the visibility of the element based on the current state..

**NOTE**: The checkbox is checked initially because the element to toggle is visible when the document loads

```js
$(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        x = $('.fc-event-container')
        // Access the element using jQuery
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            x.css({
                'visibility': 'visible'
            })
        }
        else {
            x.css({
                'visibility': 'hidden'
            })
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fc-event-container">
    Toggle the checkbox to toggle me
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="OP" name="calendario" value="OP" checked>
```

---

One thing to note about the calendar is that every time you switch the **month**, **week** or **day**, the events are rendered again..
So that means the events will have their default state which is visible every time you switch through the tabs

So if you want to ensure the element remains hidden you have to access the element only after it has been rendered, because rendering happens sequentially, so you cannot access the element as soon as rendering has started, because by then you can't know when it will render..

So the concept I've introduced is just using the property of the calendar which is `dayRender` to check when the rendering of the contents is being done, and set a timeout of half a second to return the events back to their initial state..

So that is the concept, you can read through the docs to find an event that will fire after all the rendering of the days is done and then call the function to revert back them to their visible or hidden state

Check the codepen for the working demo

Comment: I change the second line with: `$('#OP').change(function() {` and added `var x` but it's actually working thanks. I have an other issue now, i'm gonna update my question

Comment: Ok, sure please do so

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange` event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#OP').change(function() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("fc-event-container");
        if (this.checked){
             x.style.visibility = "visible !important";
        }else{
             x.style.visibility = "hidden !important";
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I tried change it, but it's still giving me "x.style is undefined" :(